# WPF ItemsControl bound to UserControls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

An `ItemsControl` binding to a collection of `UserControl` objects works fine. However, I would like to apply additional XAML, such as a `Border`, etc.

However, instead of a `Border` with the UserControl, only the UserControl itself is rendered. The `<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>` does not seem to have any effect.

**Question:** How can I design an ItemTemplate with additional XAML? Currently, this tag seems to be "ignored".

---

ViewModel: `ObservableCollection<UserControl> MyUserControls`

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyUserControls, lementName=popupContainer}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border ...>
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" />
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A look at the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ItemsControl.cs,25566aa6db31bf29,references) reveals that the [`IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.isitemitsowncontaineroverride?view=netframework-4.8) method of the ItemsControl class has this implementation:

```
protected virtual bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
{
    return (item is UIElement);
}
```

So if you pass a collection of UIElements to the ItemsSource of an ItemsControl, these elements are used directly as item containers, without the usual wrapping inside a `ContentPresenter`. Hence no `ItemTemplate` is applied at all.

So the answer to the question

> How can I design an ItemTemplate with additional XAML?

is: Not at all if the ItemsSource is a collection of UIElements.

You should instead follow the basic idea of the ItemsControl class, and assign a collection of *data item objects* to the ItemsSource property. Then select appropriate UI controls by DataTemplates that have their `DataType` property set to the types of the different data items.

---

Or you create a derived ItemsControl which overrides the `IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride` method:

```
public class MyItemsControl : ItemsControl
{
    protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your awesome answer! It covers both options: 1.) Deriving a custom `ItemsControl` class; 2.) Considering to use bindings over `UserControls`. However, I don't understand why this option is forbids that by default or why there is no public DependencyProperty for that. Since it is how it is, I will make my decision based on the given facts. Thanks!